# memory leak in NSString with ARC enable project

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

I know this question asked so many time by many developers but i have check all answers and implemented in my code but still its causing **memory leak** in `NSString`.

**Here are my code:**

```
_lblTotalOutFlowTitle.text = (APPDELEGATE.isAllSelectFilter ? APPDELEGATE.strKeyOutflow_TotalLive1 :APPDELEGATE.strKeyOutflow_Total);
```

**Memory Leak:**
 [image]

**What i tried to resolve  this leak:**

1st:

```
_lblPopulationTitle.text = [(APPDELEGATE.isAllSelectFilter ? APPDELEGATE.strKeyPopulationLive1 : APPDELEGATE.strKeyPopulation) copy];
```

2nd:

```
NSString *strPopulationLive1 = [(APPDELEGATE.isAllSelectFilter ? APPDELEGATE.strKeyPopulationLive1 : APPDELEGATE.strKeyPopulation) copy];
        _lblPopulationTitle.text = strPopulationLive1;
```

3rd:

```
 _lblPopulationTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",(APPDELEGATE.isAllSelectFilter ? APPDELEGATE.strKeyPopulationLive1 : APPDELEGATE.strKeyPopulation)];
```

`APPDELEGATE.strKeyPopulation` is string object with below property.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *strKeyPopulation;
```

any idea how to resolve this leak.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you are making copy in 2nd point. remove the copy and try if it works.

Comment: No That will also not work i have already tried without copy but still its leaking memory.

Answer (score -1):

change `strong` to `copy` ?

have a try

best wishes

Comment: this one is not allowed its my main string and didn't create it as copy type property. Thanks.

Comment: why it is not allowed?

Comment: your answer will not be helpful to user elaborate your approach and issue in existing one